# How to do something once within a click (not the entire click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have something like this:

```
someVar.click(function() {
  $(this).something.happens.here;
  $(this).something.else.happens.here;
  $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
});
```

Is it possible for the third line inside the function to be run only once on the page? The only solution I can come up with is to write a separate:

```
someVar.one( "click", function() {
      $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
    });
```

But I don't want to do this, as I'd rather keep everything in one function, mostly because of variables already defined in the first click scope.
Thanks guys.

Comment: the .one solution is the best in my opinion, otherwise you'll have additional code running on every click that prevents the third from happening.

Comment: If you don't want to use the separate call to `.one()` then you'll probably need some flag to test `something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once` against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it in the same function, you can just use a flag:

```
var shouldRun = true;
someVar.click(function() {
  $(this).something.happens.here;
  $(this).something.else.happens.here;
  if (shouldRun) {
    $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
    shouldRun = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, attaching the event with `one` is the most elegant solution. Alternatively, you could set a global variable to indicate if the function has already been run:

```
var functionHasRun = false
someVar.click(function() {
    $(this).something.happens.here;
    $(this).something.else.happens.here;
    !functionHasRun && $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
    functionHasRun = true;
});
```

If you're not a fan of globals, you could set a `data` attribute on the element which raised the event:

```
someVar.click(function() {
    $(this).something.happens.here;
    $(this).something.else.happens.here;
    !someVar.data('functionHasRun') && $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
    someVar.data('functionHasRun', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var track=true;

someVar.click(function() {
  $(this).something.happens.here;
  $(this).something.else.happens.here;
  if(track)$(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
  track=false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.one` would be what i went with, otherwise i'd just use a function that i can re-define as empty after it's been executed.

```
var onlyrunonce = function(){
    $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
    onlyrunonce = $.noop;
}

someVar.click(function(e) {
  $(this).something.happens.here;
  $(this).something.else.happens.here;
  return onlyRunOnce.call(this,e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you :

```
var handled = false;

someVar.click(function() {
  $(this).something.happens.here;
  $(this).something.else.happens.here;
  if(!handled){
      $(this).something.happens.here.that.should.only.run.once;
      handled = true;
  }

});
```